# Setting up AWS for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Being on the process of trying out `AWS` for use inside iOS apps as a server backend.
I made the sample project `WSF-aws-my-sample-app-ios-swift`, provided on the AWS site, work.

But when I want to start a project of my own, making a new one using Xcode, it doesn’t work so well any more.

I tried to bring inside my new project, what I could learn from looking at the WSF-aws-my-sample-app-ios-swift example. But I hit this issue:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x120035088 <+0>: brk    #0x3 Thread EXC_BREAKPOINT ….
```

Is there a tutorial or something similar, showing the procedure for setting AWS up, starting with a new project from Xcode, that I could follow?

Comment: Refer this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html

Comment: Thanks, it seems like you put me on the right track. Though it doesn't work yet . I having trouble finding my CognitoIdentityPoolId. I am not sure where to get that.

Comment: Ask AWS support definitely, they will help you on this.

and upvote my previous comment.